# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allennlp.data.iterators'

Tags: python, debugging, nlp, pytorch

In Google colab I am to trying import `BucketIterator` using:

```py
from allennlp.data.iterators import BucketIterator
```

But it is raising the same error again and again-

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allennlp.data.iterators
```

After installing `allennlp` with the imports:

```py
from allennlp.data.token_indexers import TokenIndexer, SingleIdTokenIndexer
from allennlp.data.tokenizers.character_tokenizer import CharacterTokenizer
from allennlp.data.vocabulary import Vocabulary
from allennlp.modules.seq2vec_encoders import PytorchSeq2VecWrapper
```

are working fine. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Which version of allennlp are you using?

Comment: @ewong I am using 1.0.0rc3 version of allennlp

Comment: From what I gathered from https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/commit/121d3eca77716336707c0e53dec22c3d80d038cc#diff-183afb393851abf956a3e00436d1184b,  it looks like BucketIterator's gone.. According to https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/releases?after=v1.0.0rc3 you need to use ```DataLoaders```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
It won't work, since Iterators are removed from allennlp.

Comment: This can be posted as a comment.

Comment: i don't know but it doesn't work with windows when you run with linux or mac it actually work well also you can use google colab to execute. i got allennlp.data.iterator and allennlp.data.dataset error when i run it on windows but when run on colab it runs without getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Install a legacy version of allennlp. allennlp is depended upon the PyTorch(torchtext) library. And since torchtext removed iterators form their newer versions allennlp did it too.

You can directly use torchtext.data.BucketIterator(). Use:

```
pip install torchtext==0.5.0 --user
```